# Using sed to replace a string containing any characters in a specific position

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a file nginx.conf as below

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {

  upstream redis {
    server 34.73.56.224:6379;
  }

  server {
    listen 8888 so_keepalive=on;
    proxy_pass redis;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a script so that when I run `bash swap.sh 400`, the address located where `34.73.56.224` currently is will be replaced by `400`; however, it won't be that number all the time--it could say a different address, or it could say redis. Note: the `:6379` should still be there after I run the script. This is what I have as of now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PARAM=$1

sed -i'.conf' "s/server .+:/server $PARAM:/" nginx.conf
```

However, this isn't working, and I think it's because I'm not using regex commands correctly. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try: `sed -E -i'.conf' "s/server .+:/server $PARAM:/" nginx.conf`

Comment: @John1024 that did the trick, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -E -i'.conf' "s/server .+:/server $PARAM:/" nginx.conf
```

By default, sed uses *Basic Regular Expressions* (BRE).  Under BRE, a `+` is a literal plus sign.  Thus, `.+` matches any character (`.`) followed by a plus sign.

You want something different: you want `.+` to match *one or more* of any character where `.` matches any character and `+` indicates *one or more*. To get this, you need *Extended Regular Expressions* (ERE).  `-E` tells sed to use ERE.